Как отключить определенное событие для элемента ListBox?
У меня есть листбокс. Я задал ему триггеры для "Мышь наведена" на элемент и для "Выбранного" элемента
Тоесть когда наводишься на элемент с ним что-то происходит( в моем случае меняются цвета) и когда он выбран тоже что-то происходит.
Из-за этого, когда я навожусь на уже выбранный элемент, изменения триггера "Мышь наведена" как бы затмевают изменения триггера "Выбранный элемент"
Я хочу чтобы при наведении на элемент, проверять выбран ли он, и если выбран то не показывать изменения, связанные с событием "Мышь наведена"
Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли так сделать?
Вот листинг стиля листбокса:
<Style x:Key="ListBox1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15, 2">
                                <Border CornerRadius="3" Width="64" Height="70" Background="#393951">
                                    <Border x:Name="icoBord" Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="48" Height="48"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="#D4D4E5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="icoBord" Property="Background" Value="#2F325A" />
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#4750D1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#2f2f40"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


Ну вот у вас есть логика и то что хотите. Реализовывайте

Наверное вас удивлю, но знал бы я КАК реализовать это все, не стал бы задавать вопрос.
P.S Зашел на ваш аккаунт. Тоесть для вас написать целый ответ что такое "Деструктивное присваивание" (Что гуглится 5 секунд) это в порядке вещей, а помочь человеку с реализаций логики на живом примере - "Ну вот у вас есть логика и то что хотите. Реализовывайте"

Нет не совсем. У вас есть код. И у вас есть проблемы с ним. Давайте листинг и попытки реализации.

Вопрос звучит довольно абстракно. У меня есть код, я хочу по другому, как сделать? Поймите проплыв за вас реку это не увеличит ваших практических навыков плавать. Я лишь хочу подтолкнуть вас к действиям, потому что у вас информации на моного больше.

@AzizUmarov Добавил листинг стиля в XAML. Попытки реализовать это кодом как таковой не было, так как не представляю как это сделать. гуглить пытался естественно, ничего не нашел.

@AzizUmarov но и вы поймите, если вы напишите мне условно КАК это сделать, вы же не сделаете это за меня, а покажите КАК(Удивительно, не правда ли?) С чего вы взяли что мои навыки в плаванье от этого не улучшаться? По вашей логике, люди которые читают книги или проходят курсы, просто используют чужой опыт а сами ничему не учатся)?

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Ну читать книги по плаванию и плавать я думаю что это разные навыки. Вы пришли с вопросом из практики при этом в книгах вы решения не нашли. Ну что вам могут посоветовать старшие коллеги. Либо плохо читали либо плавать вы без спасательного круга отказываетесь. Поймите мы все проходили это навыки решать задачи не приходят только из прочтения литературы. Не будьте диванным экспертом, а прочувствуйте на себе вкус солёной грязной не совсем приятной воды. Успехов в работе

Для решения проблемы следует использовать:
<MultiTrigger>

MultiTrigger позволяет применять изменения к элементу только в случае выполнения нескольких условий одновременно.
На всякий случай пример кода:
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#D9DEFD"/>
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
</MultiTrigger>

Этот код исполняет два setter-а только в том случае, когда и IsMouseOver равен True и IsSelected равен False.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
